# script file not found when using source

Tags: bash

I have a bash script in a file named `reach.sh`.

This file is given exe rights using `chmod 755 /Users/vb/Documents/util/bash/reach.sh`.

I then created an alias using `alias reach='/Users/vb/Documents/util/bash/reach.sh'`

*So far this works great.*

It happens that I need to run this script in my current process, so theoretically I would need to add `.` or `source` before my script path.

So I now have `alias reach='source /Users/vb/Documents/util/bash/reach.sh'`

At this point when I run my alias `reach`, the script is failing.

*Error* `/Users/vb/Documents/util/bash/reach.sh:7: = not found`

*Line 7* `if [ "$1" == "cr" ] || [ "$1" == "c" ]; then`

*Full script*

```
#!/bin/bash

# env
REACH_ROOT="/Users/vb/Documents/bitbucket/fork/self"

# process
if [ "$1" == "cr" ] || [ "$1" == "c" ]; then 
    echo -e "Redirection to subfolder"
    cd ${REACH_ROOT}/src/cr
    pwd

else 
    echo -e "Redirection to root folder"
    cd ${REACH_ROOT}
    pwd
fi
```

Any idea what I could be missing ?

Comment: Seems like the script is still found, but inside the script (at line 16 as the `:16` denotes) there is an error. Can you show us your script? Also remove the `cmd` tag. `bash` is not `cmd`.

Comment: I agree. I just added line 16 to the question

Comment: I think what you're missing is the script, in the question. :-)  Have a look at the description of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you want to do in your question is make it possible for people to replicate the problem you're having. Some issues are obvious, but this one obviously is not. We need more data. The code on line 16 may not be the issue, it could be quotes or brackets in the lines before 16.

Comment: line 16 looks good (for bash) so far. Stuff like `if [ "$1" == "cr" ] || [ "$1" == "c" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi` should work in bash even if `$1` is empty. Does the line end after `then`?

Comment: Ditch the alias, and put `/Users/vb/Documents/util/bash` in your path.

Comment: I added the full script for better clarity

Comment: @chepner when I run it without using the alias, using `source ./reach.sh` it does the same so I doubt that it is an alias related issue

Comment: It's absolutely not an alias issue; the fact that you are using an alias is both irrelevant and unnecessary, and 50% of your question shouldn't be devoted to describing how you use an alias.

Comment: That said, I can't reproduce your error using any shell I have lying around. What happens if you replace `==` with `=`?

Comment: @chepner I agree that I could do it changing my _path_ but it happens that I need to use an alias for unrelated reasons. Therefore I added the same process for reproduction purposes.

Comment: "*It happens that I need to run this script in my current process*" - what is your current process? Is it a bash shell or something else?

Comment: @chepner works ! I'm using zsh which uses sh instead of bash, makes sense now

Comment: `==` is a bash extension, you shouldn't use it if you need to run the script in another shell.

Comment: BTW, there's no point in having a `#!` line in a script that has to be sourced. That's only used when running a script as a command.

Comment: If you want to check portability of a script between shells, change the shebang to `/bin/sh` and paste it into shellcheck.net. It warns about the `=`

Comment: @Barmar I like that tip

Comment: *Please* know what shell you are actually using before asking why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running my script in `zsh` which is not a `bash` shell, so when I force it to run in my current process it runs in a `zsh` shell and does not recognize `bash` commands anymore.

Comment: Script failure has nothing to do with the Bash/ZSH, its the incorrect use of `if` condition. You can't use `[` surrounding for string comparison. Try putting `[[` and that should work. `if [[ "$1" == "cr" ]] || [[ "$1" == "c" ]]; then ` Single `[` only work if you use `-eq` style comparison with numbers and whatnot. This happens with Mac version of BSD Bash and not with AT&T version of Bash used by Ubuntu and other enterprise Linux systems.

Comment: @praveen: not so. You can do string comparison with the `[` command, but you need to spell the comparison operators correctly. Equality is spelled `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you say "It happens that I need to run this script in my current process", so I'm wondering why you are using `source` at all.  Just run the script.  Observe:

**bash-script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "aaa" ]; then
    echo "AAA"
fi
```

**zsh-script.sh**

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo "try a ..."
./bash-script.sh a
echo "try aaa ..."
./bash-script.sh aaa
echo "try b ..."
./bash-script.sh b
```

**output from `./zsh-script.sh`**

```
try a ...
try aaa ...
AAA
try b ...
```

If, in `zsh-script.sh`, I put `source` in front of each `./bash-script.sh`, I do get the behavior you described in your question.

But, if you just need to "run this script in my current process", well, then ...  just run it.

`source` tries to read a file as lines to be interpreted by the current shell, which is `zsh` as you have said.  But simply *running* it, causes the first line (the `#!/bin/bash` "shebang" line) to *start a new shell* that interprets the lines itself.  That will totally resolve the use of `bash` syntax from within a `zsh` context.